# How to combine 2 mysql queries into 1 with different where clause

Tags: php, mysql

So I need help combining 2 mysql query's into 1 query. 
So that I can insert the query into a foreach loop with php, but I'm stuck because I don't know how to do that yet! Please help.

I Would like it to return all the columns that I selected.

QUERY 1 :

```
SELECT b.id, b.post_text, c.default_photo, d.first_name, e.status 
FROM posts b 
INNER JOIN profiles c 
INNER JOIN users d 
INNER JOIN friendship e 
ON b.from_user = c.user_id 
AND b.from_user = d.id 
AND e.friend_id = b.from_user 
WHERE e.status = 'Friend' 
AND e.user_id = :id
ORDER BY b.id DESC
```

QUERY 2:

```
SELECT b.id, b.by_who_id, b.photo_dir, c.default_photo, d.first_name, e.status
FROM photos b 
INNER JOIN profiles c 
INNER JOIN users d 
INNER JOIN follower e 
ON b.by_who_id = c.user_id 
AND b.by_who_id = d.id 
AND e.from_user = b.from_user 
WHERE e.status = 'Following' 
AND e.following_who_id = :id
ORDER BY b.id DESC
```

Both query's work but I need help combining them.

**UPDATE**

ok so query 1 works perfect now the reason i want query 1 and 2 together is because it fetches data if the user is following that "something". but if he isn't following that "something" then it doesnt return anything now i want all the columns to return together.

idk if that makes sense let me know

Comment: What output should the query generate? All columns from both queries?

Comment: yes that would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` ([docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)) as long as all of your queries return same columns:

```
SELECT
    foo
FROM
    bar
WHERE
    bar.dateCreated > '2012-01-01'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    foo
FROM
    baz
WHERE
    baz.status IN (2,3);
```

Problem with your query is that there are different column sets returned from each query. Therefore you can solve this issue with `PHP`:

```
$res1 = array(/*results from query 1*/);
$res2 = array(/*results from query 2*/);

$res = array_merge($res1, $res2);

foreach($res as $r){
    if(array_key_exists('post_text', $r){
       //result came from first resultset, process it here
    } elseif(array_key_exists('by_who_id', $r) {
       //result came from second resultset, process it here
    } else {
       //cannot resolve from which resultset this particular result came, throw exception
       throw new Exception('Cannot handle results - unrecognized result');
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. Please give us a broader picture of what do you want to do. [The XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Well, this is exactly what my code did. By broader picture I mean - not what do you want to do, but **why**, because maybe there's simplier solution.

Comment: Do you want to select some posts and have photos related to those posts?

Comment: lol no so i have some post and photo and post and photo but that if query 2 returns anything it can be post post photo post photo photo whatever they both return but post and photos are seperate.
can this be done with both php and mysql method you specified

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you have the same query with different status filter and extra column names. Just use the the statement "WHERE e.status IN ('status1', 'status2')" and all field list you need in both cases to solve your issue.

Comment: doesn't work because it query 1 checks to see if they are friends and query two checks if i'm following something

Comment: OK, I see. In this case see the UNION or PHP foreach array merge solutions.